# How to replicate a 'new Date()' format?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

**What I'm Using**

- Angular Material Date Picker
- Moment.js
- Firestore

**What I'm doing**

- When I create a new item and add it to firestore, I add a date by using 'new Date()'
- This creates the following format it firestore: **October 13, 2017 at 9:00:04 AM UTC+1**
- This is exactly what I want
- The material date picker reads this perfectly fine and displays **13/10/2017**

**What I'd like to do**

- If I edit the item and select a new date from the material date picker and hit update, I want to convert the date picker value, which is currently a string of **18/12/2017** (for example...)
- Before writing back to the database, I would like that format to be something like **December 18, 2017 at 9:00:04 AM UTC+1**

**Questions**

- How would I go about doing that?
- Is it a moment.js conversion?
- Or are there options with the material date picker that can help me?

**Component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input #newItemDate #picker matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" (focus)="picker.open()" formControlName="item_date">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>


<button (click)="dateTest(newItemDate.value)"> Test Date </button>
```

**Component.ts**

Obviously, not much here :) - But this is where I need to have the converted date

```js
  dateTest(newItemDate) {    

    // newItemDate = 13/10/2017  

    // I need October 13, 2017 at 9:00:04 AM UTC+1
   
  }
```

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can easily post what isn't working hence why I'm here...it won't however change what my question is and what I need help with.

Comment: You need to post the code you tried that isn't working. And a minimal example, not everything.

Comment: The verbose Date representation is a standard, but a database SQL DATETIME would rather be filled just by a Date object, and SQL would officiall go for '2017-12-18T17:30:00' or variations thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in date formatting functions:

```
 dateTest(newItemDate) {    

    var formatedDate = new Date(newItemDate);

    // UTC Date
    console.log(formatedDate.toUTCString());

    // ISO Date
    console.log(formatedDate.toISOString());

  }
```

Link to [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-11-7z6ume?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Hi Faisal. My date locale might be set to either UK or US. In your example it's US. When mine is set to UK in this instance, i get the following errors:
"UTC = Invalid Date" / "ISO = ERROR RangeError: Invalid time value"

Comment: I've tested it with the US pattern and it works perfectly. I can read and write to firestore like a charm. The moment I use "dateAdapter.setLocale('en-gb');", it doesn't work.

Comment: see the updated demo. I have added method to format `en-GB` to `en-US` format and then continue with date conversion.

Comment: Thank you. Absolute wizard. Also, thank you @OArnarsson for taking the time to respond :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a moment out of the string and formatting it like so:

```js
// dateTest(newItemDate) {  

// This way you can make a moment right from the string :)
let newItemDate = moment('13/10/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format("MMMM DD, YYYY H:MM:SS A Z");
console.log(newItemDate);

// }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: Fixed the missing moment.js import in snippet.

Comment: Hey @OArnarsson! Thanks for the response! :). My console reads: The date you entered is: 1456444800000. Could this be a material date picker thing?

Comment: @MegaTron I've updated the snippet, does it still give you epoch time?

Comment: Hey dude, thanks! That looks closer. But moment logs an error to the console: "moment.min.js:23 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info."

Comment: @MegaTron I updated once again, does that still produce an error?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. :( I appreciate your time checking this out. Very kind =)